# Error in Overriding alert with console.log function in javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, overriding, console.log

I am new to javascript. Due to certain reasons, I need to override windows.alert function by console.log function. For that, I have written following code,

```
window.alert        = console.log;
alert('abc'); // gives TypeError : Illegal invocation.
```

I don't know what's wrong I am doing here. As per my knowledge, it's possible to modify javascript function reference with another function object.

**Edit**

Many have downvoted my question and given me reference to similar question, but 
my problem is different. I want to suppress the warning of datatable grid library in jquery. That's why I want to replace alert by console.log or other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this should work...

```
alert("msg");

function alert(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
var alert = (...params) => console.log(...params);
```

Comment: Can you make me understand the above fancy code ? Or Can you give me any reference to it ?

Comment: It's ES6. The alert function replaces the default alert function and ...params makes sure that whatever argument the log method can take, it mutates it in the alert function. I'm sure u know the log method can take more than an argument, so as the declared alert function.